# Why doesn't remove_reference work on functions?

Tags: c++, templates, types, c++17, function-qualifier

Ran into something strange when doing some template metaprogramming the other day. It basically comes down to this assertion not (as I would expect) passing.

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<void(), std::remove_reference_t<void()&>>);
```

At first I thought I was making a syntactic mistake defining a function reference, but this assertion passes, showing that's not the case.

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<void()&, void()&>);
```

I also tried implementing `remove_reference` myself copying the source from cppreference but that didn't work either. What is going on here?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Welcome to the world of Abominable Function Types.

`void() &` is *not* a reference to `void()`. The way to spell that would be `void(&)()` (which if you `remove_reference_t`, you would get back `void()` -- that is `remove_reference_t` *does* work on references to functions, if what you provide it is actually a reference to function type).

What `void() &` actually refers to is the type of a reference-qualified member function after you strip off the class. That is:

```
struct C {
    void f() &;
};
```

The type of `&C::f` is `void (C::*)() &`. But all pointers to members can be written as `T C::*` for some type `T`, and in this case the type `T` would be `void() &`.

See also [P0172](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/p0172r0.html).

Comment: Someone should create a canonical question for abominable function types.

Comment: Wow, C++ never fails to surprise me even if I have learned and used it for almost 10 years.

Comment: @KelvinHu what? that's C... function type is `void (void)`. Pointer to function is  `void (*) (void)`. And some returned type-declarators would "creep over the head" and appear after argument list. Good old K&R. All that C++ added where qualifiers and ability to make in a member:  `void (Class::*) (/*skip the void*/) /*const/ref-qualifier*/`.

Answer (score 13):

The type you have is not a reference to a function, but a function with a [reference qualifier](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2014/06/02/ref-qualifiers/).

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<void()&, void()&>);
static_assert(!std::is_same_v<void()&, void(&)()>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<void(&)(), void(&)()>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<void(), std::remove_reference_t<void(&)()>>);
```